# The most efficient nested array container in C++ for reading and writing?

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array

I am a mathematician by training and need to simulate a continuous time Markov chain. I need to use a variant of Gillespie algorithm which relies on fast reading and writing to a 13-dimensional array. At the same time, I need to set the size of each dimension based on users input (they will be each roughly of order 10). Once these sizes are set by the user, they will not change throughout the runtime. The only thing which changes will be the data contained in them. What is the most efficient way of doing this?

My first try was to use the standard arrays but their sizes must be known at the compilation time, which is not my case. Is std::vector a good structure for this? If so, how shall I go about initializing a creature as:

```
vector<vector<vector<vector<vector<vector<vector<vector<vector<vector<vector<vector<vector<int>>>>>>>>>>>>> Array;
```

Will the initialization take more time than dealing with an array? Or, is there a better data container to use, please?

Thank you for any help!

Comment: A single vector, not 13 nested ones.  You then figure out where `array(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,...etc).` is located in the single vector.

Comment: Although even a single vector could be an issue if you expect it to be containing around 10 trillion entries.

Comment: C++ is the most complicated general purpose programming language in use today. Attempting to implement a relatively complicated process in C++, without having much experience with it, will only end in tears. It's entirely possible that the requirements for this 13-dimensional array are as such as it can be efficiently modeled using one of the unordered containers, with a 13-dimensional tuple as the container key. Can't say without having complete knowledge of both the nature of the data being modeled (whether it's sparse, or not), as well as in-depth C++ knowledge.

Comment: I have been thinking about it first but there is a problem. I need to use the Next Reaction Method as described in https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/jp993732q#. But each of the reactions is uniquelly specified by 6 parameters. So, this leads to a requirement of 6+6=12 dimensions required for the dependency graph. (Oh sorry, 12 not 13.) If I used single array, how would I inversely knew each of the 6 parameters specifying each reaction? I would need to somehow encode 6 numbers to a single number, which would be in the single array. This is possible, but would take way to much time when decoding.

Comment: Oh, I see what you meant PaulMcKenzie, I might try that thing. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would start by using a [std::unordered_map](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) to hold key-value pairs, with each key being a 13-dimensional [std::array](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array), and each value being an `int` (or whatever datatype is appropriate), like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <array>

typedef std::array<int, 13> MarkovAddress;

// Define a hasher that std::unordered_map can use
// to compute a hash value for a MarkovAddress
// borrowed from:  https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/172095/126857
template<class T, size_t N>
struct std::hash<std::array<T, N>> {
   size_t operator() (const std::array<T, N>& key) const {
      std::hash<T> hasher;
      size_t result = 0;
      for(size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i) { 
         result = result * 31 + hasher(key[i]); // ?? 
      }
      return result;
   }
};

int main(int, char **)
{
   std::unordered_map<MarkovAddress, int> map;

   // Just for testing
   const MarkovAddress a{{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13}};

   // Place a value into the map at the specified address
   map[a] = 12345;

   // Now let's see if the value is present in the map,
   // and retrieve it if so
   if (map.count(a) > 0)
   {
      std::cout << "Value in map is " << map[a] << std::endl;
   }
   else std::cout << "Value not found!?" << std::endl;

   return 0;
}
```

That will give you fast (O(1)) lookup and insert, which is likely your first priority.  If you later run into trouble with that (e.g. too much RAM used, or you need a well-defined iteration order, or etc) you could replace it with something more elaborate later.